# My textures aren't rendering correctly

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I initialize the window as an 800x600

```
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
        Display.create();
        Mouse.create();
        Keyboard.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then I create an 800x100 button with 800x100 textures

```
public MenuButton(int x, int y, int height, int width, Texture tex, Texture border){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x2 = x + width;
    this.y2 = y + height;
    this.tex = tex;
    this.border = border;
}
```

And then I try to render it

```
this.border.bind();
Color.white.bind();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(this.x, this.y2);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(this.x2, this.y2);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(this.x2, this.y);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(this.x, this.y);
glEnd();
```

But instead of going all the way across the display like it should, it goes about 80% of the way and has two wierd lines on the edge of the display and under the button. [Ignore the texture on top, look at the rectangle that says play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjX2P.jpg).